# How to handle "accept cookies"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to make a scraper that gets the reviews for hotel on tripadvisor.com. I was just working with pagination and testing if the browser would go all the way to the end, where there is no more pages.

Here is my code so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g298656-Ankara-Hotels.html');

    while(true) {

        await page.click('a[class="nav next ui_button primary"]');
        await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    } 

}

main();
```

However, this stops when the 'accept cookies' popup appears. How can I handle this?

Comment: Does the popup appear in dom? You may want to check for the popup after every click and accept it. When I open the page, no popup appears at all.  Another idea would be to manually click the "cookie consent" button after page is loaded and accept all cookies.

Comment: By manually I mean via puppeteer ofc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to close the cookies popup by clicking on it via Puppeteer:

```
const button = await page.$('[aria-label="Only allow essential cookies"]');
if (button) {
    await button.click();
}
```

Inspect the DOM after the cookie popup appears to see the best way to select the button you need.